# Fuzzy Merge on Multiple columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to merge 2 dataset by 3 columns fuzzy match to nearest values.

below is the code I tried, but I get below error.
any idea how to fuzzy merge by multiple columns?

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tolist

```
Key1 = ['Prod ID complete', 'Client name complete', 'Amount']
Key2 = ['Product ID Incomplete', 'Client name', 'Amount']

def fuzzy_merge(df_1, df_2, Key1, Key2, threshold=90, how='outer', limit=1):
    s = df_2[Key2].tolist()
    m = df_1[Key1].apply(lambda x: process.extract(x, s, limit=limit))    
    df_1['matches'] = m
    m2 = df_1['matches'].apply(lambda x: ', '.join([i[0] for i in x if 
    i[1] 
    >= threshold]))
    df_1['matches'] = m2
    return df_1
fuzzy_merge(Data1, Data2, Key1, Key2, threshold=85)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **values** first. Because **[`tolist`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html)** works with numpy arrays. But you are setting dataframe instead of an array. Convert it to array using **values** ​​then convert array to list.
:

```
s = df_2[Key2].values.tolist()
```

Note:

```
print(type(df[['name','Id']].values))
#<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: When I try this I get this error "TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object"

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the error on this line?

Comment: I'm getting the error when I apply the fuzzy_merge function                                                      fuzzy_merge(Data1, Data2, Key1, Key2, threshold=85)

Comment: in the full error message(traceback), it says which line the error is on. please Check the error message find which line is wrong.

Comment: I get error in line 3                                                                                                                 ----> 3     m = df_1[key1].apply(lambda x: process.extract(x, s, limit=limit))